# How to keep model state in a MVC4 view....?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a MVC4 application.

In it there is a view in which the user is allowed to create a list of questions.

Each question is added one by one.

Where  i stand now is on addition of every question i have to invoke the controller and then add the question in the Data Base. Which is not appropriate because it would be extremely hard if the user want to edit any question.

i want the view to handle every thing. As the questions are been added the should recite on the client side in a list of question in my model. And on the click on some final button it should go to the controller  and from there to data base.

My question adding method is when a question and all its choices are entered in model bounded textboxes.. When the user press add question the question should be added to the list and the textboxes will again be null.

Kindly suggest me some topics or methods that i can look into to accomplish my task. I guess it would be possible using JQuesry or AJAX. But i have very little knowledge of it.. So i really require help.. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly suggest me some topics or methods that i can look into to accomplish my task.

1. If you want to use AJAX: [`Editing variable length list`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)
2. With knockoutjs: [`Editing variable length list - knockout style`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/)

Comment: This does not solve my problem. the user will write a question and all its answers and then it will be added in to the models's list and then the user will write next question and all its answers and then the 2nd question will be added to to the model's list...